# system wide shortcut for start speaking not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: keyboard, speech

I added a shortcut for "start speaking"
[image]
it works in Safari: I can select a piece of text then use the shortcut to make my Mac read it aloud for me
While in Edge, it stops working, though I can see the shortcut is set in the menu bar:
[image]
Is there ways to make it also work in Edge? I do need this functionality.

Comment: Typically if a system wide shortcut is not working in.a particular app, it is due to an issue with the App itself.  [Feedback should be submitted to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332)

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem with your shortcut but why aren't you using the text-to-speech built-in feature? It's in System Prefs > Accessibility > Spoken Content >  turn on “Speak selection.”

Comment: @Allan I did submit the feedback there, but I think it might be helpful to ask this question here as well.

Comment: @Thinkr It's because I didn't know the existence of that... Oh my, it should be what I'm looking for! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't solve the problem with your shortcut not working but why aren't you using the text-to-speech built-in feature?

It is located in *System Preferences > Accessibility > Spoken Content*. To enable it, turn on “**Speak selection**”.

The default keyboard shortcut for this is <kbd>⌥ Option (Alt)</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>. You need to press those keys when a text is selected (anywhere) to start reading. To stop reading, you will need to press <kbd>⌥ Option (Alt)</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> again.